# nosetests is capturing the output of my print statements. How to circumvent this?

Tags: python, nosetests

When I type

```
$ nosetests -v mytest.py
```

all my print outputs are captured when all tests pass.
I want to see print outputs even everything passes.

So what I'm doing is to force an assertion error to see the output, like this.

```
class MyTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.debug = False

    def test_0(self):
        a = .... # construct an instance of something
        # ... some tests statements
        print a.dump()
        if self.debug:
            eq_(0,1)
```

It feels so hackish, there must be a better way. Enlighten me please.

Comment: Any idea how to do it programatically?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Either:

```
$ nosetests --nocapture mytest.py
```

Or:

```
$ NOSE_NOCAPTURE=1 nosetests mytests.py
```

(it can also be specified in the `nose.cfg` file, see `nosetests --help`)

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. I also found it helpful to know I could pass this argument into nose.main() as described in the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070501/passing-options-to-nose-in-a-python-test-script

Comment: In case anyone want to see the source: http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/capture.html

Comment: The short version of this command is `nosetests -s`.  For other standard options, see either the `-h` help or the [basic usage](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#selecting-tests) help page.

Comment: python3.5 -m "nose" --nocapture

Comment: doesn't work for me, even with this option my print statements aren't printed when the tests pass

Answer (score 17):

Use

```
--nologcapture
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 10):

This was added recently to nose instead of `--nocapture` do this:

```
nosetests -s
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @BhargavRao "do this nosetests -s" answers the question (albeit, without the littlest regard for grammar).  i'm not sure why you're objecting.

Comment: Note that `-s` is the single letter abbreviation of the `--nocapture` flag as [per the documentation](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/capture.html).

Answer (score 3):

In order to integrate with http://travis-ci.org I have put this into **.travis.yml**:

```
script:  "python setup.py nosetests -s"
```

---

where *setup.py* contains:

```
setup(
    ...
    tests_require=['nose>=1.0'],
    test_suite='nose.collector',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
nosetests -v 2 -s yourtest
```

Flags expect order.