# Passing options to nose in a Python test script

Tags: python, nose

Rather than running my nose tests from the command line, I'm using a test runner that sets up a few things for all the tests, including a connection to a local test instance of MongoDB. The documentation for nose only seems to indicate how to pass options through the command line or a configuration file located in your home directory. Is there a way to pass options, such as --with-xunit when using a script to run your tests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
import nose

argv = ['fake', '--with-xunit']
nose.main(argv=argv)
```

The "fake" argument must be added to stand in for the executable name, as described in dbw's answer.

Comment: @Matt: Are you sure ? because i'm using the same snippet of code in one my project, and i just changed now to generate an `xunit` report and it was generated successfully under `nosetests.xml` !? maybe i'm missing something ...

Comment: Yeah, I tried this first and a report was not generated. Tried with command line and I got one. Sorry :-/

Comment: I use `nose.core.run()` to run nose programmatically. Not sure what the difference is to `main()`.

Comment: @Santa: you can read it in the docstring  of the two function here what it say: `The arguments to run() are the same as to main(): ... With the exception that the ``exit`` argument in run() is always set to False` and in main it's set by default to True which mean that nose will exit after running tests and printing report.

Comment: I think I know why this didn't work.  Nose does not use the first argument to argv to configure itself.  This may have also caused problems with parallel execution?

Comment: argv = ['fake_executable_name', '--with-xunit'] will fix the problem

Comment: First element of `sys.argv` is the scripts filename, so try to use `argv = [sys.argv[0], '--with-xunit']`.

Comment: Or even better: `sys.argv.extend(['--with-xunit']); nose.main(argv=sys.argv)`.

Comment: This answer should be modified to include and empty first arg.  It is not correct.

Answer (score 18):

Nose does something sneaky with the first argument, so it is not parsed.  My nose wrapper does something like this:

```
import nose
import sys

argv = sys.argv[:]
argv.insert(1, "--with-xunit")
nose.main(argv=argv)
```

As a bonus, this allows the clients of your program to use Nose arguments to control its behavior!

Comment: I believe this is the more correct answer.  The point about Nose being sneaky with the first argument is a very important point.

Comment: nose is not sneaky :) The point is that `argv` list always starts with the name of the executable. Thus, when you say `argv = ['--with-xunit']`, you set the name of the executable to `--with-xunit`, and pass no arguments. To fix this, use `argv = ['fake', '--with-xunit']`

Comment: I suppose this was my implicit point, thanks for making it explicit.  The first "argument" is used to make suer that help is printed correctly, etc.