# python nose test reporting in teamcity

Tags: python, unit-testing, teamcity, nose

I have a script call `run_test.py`, here's the content:-

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    nose.main(argv=sys.argv)
```

Running all my tests is as simple as doing this:

```
run_test.py unittests/test_*.py
```

I'm trying to now incorperate the output reporting for this into teamcity.
I'm referring to this https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-messages

I tried changing all my unittests/test_*.py program following the documentation. It works if running the test individually like this:-

```
unittest/test_one.py
```

But it does not work when running it thru nose, like this:

```
run_test.py unittest/test_one.py
```

According to the documentation link, it says that nose reporting is enabled automatically under TeamCity build. I don't quite get what that means.

Is there anything that i'm missing out here?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the way to achieve that.
Here's what i modified in my run_test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import unittest

from teamcity import is_running_under_teamcity
from teamcity.unittestpy import TeamcityTestRunner



loader = unittest.TestLoader()
start_dir = sys.argv[1]
suite = loader.discover(start_dir, pattern='test_*.py')

#runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
runner = TeamcityTestRunner(verbosity=2)
runner.run(suite)
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the [xunit plugin](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/xunit.html) of nose.
it will generate an xml file with the results => which jenkins and teamcity can use.

[some documentation for teamcity](https://xunit.net/docs/getting-test-results-in-teamcity)

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070501/passing-options-to-nose-in-a-python-test-script) tells you how to enable the plugin in your test script

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    argv = sys.argv[:]
    argv.insert(1, "--with-xunit")
    nose.main(argv=argv)
```