# How to configure python nosetests to run print() statements?

Tags: python, nose

While I know that this can be done from the command line `nosetests --nocapture test.py`

I would like to know if is it possible to add code into `test.py` so that I can just type `nosetests test.py` without adding `--nosecapture`.

Comment: why do you want this?

Comment: answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975194/nosetests-is-capturing-the-output-of-my-print-statements-how-to-circumvent-this)

Answer (score 9):

You can see the print statements by adding the `-s` flag to your terminal command. e.g.

```
$ nosetests -s test.py
```

**-s, --nocapture**

Don’t capture stdout (any stdout output will be printed immediately) [NOSE_NOCAPTURE].

Check the official document [here](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

Comment: Hello, please add some explanation to your answer so it has more detail and easier to understand/follow.

Comment: it works for me, this is should be an accepted answer I think :)

Answer (score 7):

You can do it by either defining environment `NOSE_NOCAPTURE` variable, creating `.noserc` or `nose.cfg` file in your home directory that will have something like:

```
[nosetests]
nocapture=1
```

or by passing arguments to nose directly in python when calling `nose.run()` as described [in nose documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html)