# Detailed information on tests with nosetests --with-html-out

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I am playing a bit with `nosetests` and I am missing the feature where I can output detailed information about the tests.

For example I am testing a colored spectrum random generator where the asserts are put on particular frequencies. However, It would be interesting to output an html report with a frequency plot and some statistics about the test.

At the end of the day I would like to be able to insert in the report some detailed information in such manner:

```
def test():
   """ Example. """
   report.insertPlot() #numpy plot
   report.insertText("Some text")
   report.insertSeparator() # would probably insert a <hr> tag
```

I currently notice that just doing this below does not work.

```
def test():
   """ Example. """
   print "Some text that I wish to see in my report"
```

How to generate a detailed test report with `nose`?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975194/nosetests-is-capturing-the-output-of-my-print-statements-how-to-circumvent-this

Comment: First install coverage for nose, then type $nosetest --with-coverage test.py, and that should give you detailed information about your test

Comment: @PetarP I don't think `coverage` is related to this quesiton. My idea is to record *manual* information from a test function.