# How to run python unittest inside PyCharm with buffer=True

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

Building on top of [How to assert output with nosetest/unittest in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219717/how-to-assert-output-with-nosetest-unittest-in-python) I would like to acieve this inside Pyharm. However, pycharm does not run:

```
$ python -m tests.test_mymodule --buffer
```

Rather it does:

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.7 /opt/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py \
  /home/oz123/PycharmProjects/account/tests/test_mymodule.py true
```

So, I ran it with:

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.7 /opt/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py \
  /home/oz123/PycharmProjects/account/tests/test_mymodule.py --buffer true
```

And it crashes with:

```
##teamcity[testFinished duration='72' name='test_1_list_files']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 151, in <module>
    TeamcityTestRunner().run(all, **options)
  File "/opt/helpers/pycharm/tcunittest.py", line 249, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/suite.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/suite.py", line 108, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/suite.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/suite.py", line 108, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 396, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 356, in run
    result.addError(self, sys.exc_info())
  File "/opt/helpers/pycharm/tcunittest.py", line 108, in addError
    TestResult.addError(self, test, err)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/result.py", line 19, in inner
    return method(self, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/result.py", line 116, in addError
    self.errors.append((test, self._exc_info_to_string(err, test)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/result.py", line 167, in _exc_info_to_string
    output = sys.stdout.getvalue()
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'getvalue'
```

Does any one know where does pycharm store the output? How can I access it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: not that I remember. I stopped using PyCharm and went back to vim ...