# Test function appends NONE during end of unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x

I've been working on some code to practice unit testing. The original is supposed to get all file names in a directory, and list the number of files with the same extension. When I run the same function using unittest, the test appends a `None` at the end, breaking the test.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import os
from glob import glob
from collections import Counter

directory = os.getcwd()
filetype = "*.*"

def lookUp(directory, filetype):
    """Returns filename in the current directory"""
    files = [os.path.basename(i) for i in
            glob(os.path.join(directory,filetype))]
    countExt = Counter([os.path.splitext(i)[1] for i in files])
    for i in countExt:
        print("There are %d file(s) with the %s extension" %
        (countExt[i], i))
```

returns this output:

```
There are 3 file(s) with the .html extension
There are 1 file(s) with the .txt extension
There are 2 file(s) with the .py extension
There are 3 file(s) with the .doc extension
```

and my unittest code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import unittest
import FileHandling
import os
import tempfile
from glob import glob



class TestFileHandling(unittest.TestCase): #Defines TestHandling class

    def setUp(self): # define seUp function
        self.testdir = os.getcwd()
        #self.testdir = tempfile.mkdtemp("testdir") # creates a test directory
        os.chdir(self.testdir) # changes to test directory
        self.file_names = ["file1.txt", "file1.doc", "file2.doc", "file3.doc", "file1.html", "file2.html", "file3.html"] # name seven filenames
        for fn in self.file_names: # creates files
            joinedfile = os.path.join(self.testdir, fn) #joins the filename with the temp directory name
            f = open(joinedfile, "w") # create the file
            f.close() # close the file from writing



    def test_lookUp_text(self): # test function for lookUp
        print(FileHandling.lookUp(self.testdir, "*.*"))
        #print(os.getcwd())
        #self.assertEqual(files, expected,)



def tearDown(self):
    for fn in self.file_names:
        os.remove(joinedfile)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

returns this output:

```
There are 2 file(s) with the .py extension
There are 3 file(s) with the .doc extension
There are 1 file(s) with the .txt extension
There are 3 file(s) with the .html extension
None
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.016s

OK
```

Why is there an additional `None` output at the end of the unittest output?

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't use a `return` statement, so Python returns `None` (the default). You are printing that value. Note that your test isn't broken by it, your test is actually not testing anything, only running the code.

Simply remove your `print()` call:

```
def test_lookUp_text(self):
    FileHandling.lookUp(self.testdir, "*.*")
```

You should consider changing your function to *return* the a report to print rather than print directly, then your unit test more easily can make assertions about the right output having been produced.

You should also consider learning how the [`unittest.mock` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) could help you here; you could mock out the `os.listdir()` call so you don't actually have to create test files, and instead leave it to your mocked `os.listdir()` call to return a pre-determined list of strings.

Comment: HI, thanks for the response. I should have been clearer in my original post, the print was just there for my own diagnostics purposes. When I remove the print i get "AssertionError: None != 'There are 1 file(s) with the .txt extension'", which I assumed was from the trailing NONE output. Thanks

Comment: @user3830278: again, your function doesn't return anything. It *prints*, which means the output is written to `sys.stdout`. You could try and capture that but it'd be easier if your function instead returned a string or list.

Comment: @user3830278: see [How to assert output with nosetest/unittest in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4219717) for an example that captures stdout, but since you are trying out unittesting it would be far easier for you to build a string and return that to test.

Comment: Hey Martijn, thanks so much for your help, I finally realized what you meant. I used a dict object for the results, and printed the dict object in the FileHandling program while returning the dict object to the testing and it worked like a cham. Thanks!