# Basic If Statement Unittesting

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

**Background:** Unittesting beginner here. Trying to develop of habit of Test Driven Development when writing code. So I made a simple odd or even number calculator and want to test every angle of this simple program

**Code for simple odd/even number checker**

```
def get_odd_even(numb):
    if numb % 4 == 0:
        print("This number is a multiple of 4")
    elif numb % 2 == 0:
        print("This number is even")
    else:
        print("This number is odd")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    numb = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    get_odd_even(numb)
```

**Unittest to check odd number conditional is working**

```
import unittest
from odd_even import get_odd_even


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_odd(self):
        self.assertEqual(get_odd_even(7), "This number is odd", "Should read this as an odd number")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Traceback**

```
This number is odd
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_odd (__main__.MyTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_odd_even.py", line 7, in test_odd
    self.assertEqual(get_odd_even(7),True, "Should read this as an odd number")
AssertionError: None != True : Should read this as an odd number

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

**What I've Also Attempted:**

Assuming since the if statement is looking for a boolean response that I assert my argument of 7 is == to True `self.assertEqual(get_odd_even(7), True, "Should read this as an odd number")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assertEqual` will check if its first two arguments are equal. That means it is testing whether the return value of `get_odd_even` is the same as `True`. However, your `get_odd_even` function does not return a value. That's why you're getting `AssertionError: None != True`. You should either alter `get_odd_even` to return strings instead of printing them, or look into [asserting output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219717/how-to-assert-output-with-nosetest-unittest-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: Ah! So simple. I didn't realise you could `return "a string like this"` either. Amazing, thank you for this!